# Referencing the last vector in a matrix in python cycle

Tags: python, for-loop, matrix, vector

I'm trying to run a cycle that takes a matrix, vector-by-vector, then multiplies these vectors into a new matrix with some variation in each.
My code, however does not only alter the last-added vector, but all of them.
Here's a simplified sample:

```
origVector = [0,0,0,0]
nVectors=[]
for j in range(3):
    print ("iteration: " + str(j))
    nVectors.append(origVector)
    nVectors[-1][0] += j+1 
    #at this point it should only change the last-added vector, 
    #but it changes them all
    print(nVectors)
```

I've spent the last half day trying to figure out what's wrong with my referencing (for e.g. the matrixname[-1][0] reference is working fine if not inside the cycle)
Can someone please point me to the direction..? Thanx in advance!

Comment: Because you append `origVector` each time, what you have changed is `origVector`. You should append a copy of it, using `nVectors.append(origVector[:])`

Comment: that solves it, thanks!
I'm wondering why it would change the original vector in the first place...

Comment: Because in `nVectors.append(origVector)` it is passed by reference.